# Replicate effect from select to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently i have this html:

```
  <div class="limit">
      <select onchange="location = this.value;">
       <option value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=24" selected="selected">24</option>
        <option value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=48">48</option>
        <option value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=72">72</option>
        <option value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=96">96</option>
        <option value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=120">120</option>
        <option value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=9999">ALL</option>
       </select>
    </div>
```

and in my .js file it is used this one:

```
if ($(".limit select").length) {
    $(".limit select").get(0).onchange = null;
    $(".limit select").change(function () {
        $("#filterpro_limit").val(gUV($(this).val(), "limit"));
        iF()
    });
}
```

What i want actually is to show the options of the select in a row outside of the dropdown, so my idea was do remove the above html and use this one:

```
 <div class="limit">
       <div data-value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=24">24</div>
       <div data-value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=48">48</div>
       <div data-value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=72">72</div>
       <div data-value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=96">96</div>
       <div data-value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=120">120</div>
        <div data-value="http://example.net/mycategory?limit=9999">ALL</div>
     </div>
```

and in js to use something like this:

```
 if ($(".limit div").length) {
        $(".limit div").get(0).onclick = null;
        $(".limit div").click(function () {
            $("#filterpro_limit").val(gUV($(this).val(), "limit"));
            iF()
        });
    }
```

but somehow i cannot make the js to work correctly to have the similar effect. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Since you're asking a question about how to do something client-side, instead of quoting PHP code that generates HTML, quote example **HTML**. Ideally as a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: Open up your html via `view page source` and copy the html there into here instead. Try to make it a snippet

Comment: Ok i removed php and copied code from source code!

Comment: You have an extra `iF()` there...just sayin'. And what is `gUV()`?

Comment: This is exactly what the code is by default (i mean with the extra if)

Comment: I'm a bit unclear what you want to do... do you want to show the selected limit in a separate text box or what?

Comment: First of all this selector `$(".limit div")` is wrong here because it will get all `div`s in an element that has class `limit` so you need to change it to  `$("div.limit")`

Comment: I want to show options outside of select box, so i want to replace actually the first html with the select with the second html with the divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code there are few mistakes that should be corercted:

- First of all this selector `$(".limit div")` is wrong here because it will get all `div`s inside an element that has class `limit` so you need to change it to  `$("div.limit")` in order to get the wanted div.
- You are using `$(this).val()` on a div element which doesn't have `.val()` because it's not an `input` or a `select`, you need to change it to `$(this).attr("data-value")` along with the right selector.
- And speaking about the right selector to get the div options inside your `.limit` div you need to use `$("div.limit div")` and there's no need to use `.get(0)` with this selctor.

So your code need to be changed as follow:

```
if ($("div.limit").length) {
    $("div.limit div").onclick = null;
    $("div.limit div").click(function() {
        $("#filterpro_limit").val(gUV($(this).attr("data-value"), "limit"));
        iF()
    });
}
```

**Note:**

And note that you will need to change the `.limit` div and its children style to get it work as a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Although building this yourself is rewarding, you might want to look at https://select2.github.io/. That is what you want, but then nicer ;-). Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $example = $(".js-example-programmatic").select2();
    $(".js-programmatic-set-val").on("click", function () { $example.val("AL").trigger("change"); });
});
</script>

<select class="js-example-programmatic">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>

<button class="js-programmatic-set-val btn btn-default">Set "Alabama"</button>
```

More info can be found here: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic

Comment: I have seen select2 but haven't found example of how practically show options inline and not inside a nicer select box

Comment: @JoostS it's a link-only answer... (but the downvote wasn't mine)

Comment: Thank you JoostS for this solution i just tried it and its working. If i could mark 2 answers as correct i would mark this one also but because in original post i have the code, i marked chsdk's answer as correct because its a working example using the specific code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value inside `div` use `.text()` instead of `.val()`
So you code should be

```
if ($(".limit div").length) {
        $(".limit div").get(0).onclick = null;
        $(".limit div").click(function () {
            $("#filterpro_limit").text(gUV($(this).data('value'), "limit"));
        });
    }
```

Assuming that `iF()` is a `function` you have created.

Comment: I need to get value attribute of div. If you see in my example i use data-value as attribute and that's what i need to get

Comment: so for that use `.data(value)`

Comment: If i use $("#filterpro_limit").val(gUV($(this).data(value), "limit")); iget console error: value is not defined

Comment: I have updated the answer. Sorry for some mistakes :)